# MultiLibraryClassLoader Error

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm writing a rviz panel.

When I change namespace (tiffer_panel -> Tiffer) in my code, and change the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS.

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(Tiffer::TifferPanel,rviz::Panel )
```

After Compiled, when I run `rviz` with this panel, got this

```
PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'Tiffer' failed to load.  Error: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create class of type tiffer_panel::TifferPanel
```

It seems not change. But when I change the namespace back (Tiffer -> tiffer_panel), it works well again...

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291030/multilibraryclassloader-error/) by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2018-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:
Did you also update your `plugin.xml` (or whatever you named that file)?

**Comment by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on 2018-05-14**:
I did not find this file,can you plz tell me where it is?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:
It doesn't have to have exactly that name. But there should be a file that registers your plugin with the ROS plugin system. It's typically called `plugin.xml` and is referenced in your package's `package.xml`.

**Comment by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on 2018-05-14**:
Thanks, I'll try it later.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-04**:
I had a similar error for a different problem, using the class_loader to make a MoveGroup capability. If anyone comes here searching: Make sure to modify not only the class files and the `xml` file, but also the `CMakeLists.txt` to generate the executable for the class you are trying to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem by modifving `plugin_description.xml`

```
<library path="libtiffer_panel">
  <class name="Tiffer"
         type="Tiffer::TifferPanel"
         base_class_type="rviz::Panel">
    <description>
      Tiffer's simple panel.
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

Just modify the `type` to what you change in your code.

---

Originally posted by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) with karma: 96 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1